# Realtime Wireless Heart Rate Monitor

Tags: sensor, wireless

I'm familiar with Assembly/C/C++, so this question is focused on the hardware side.

Context: I want to have a real time heart rate monitor so that I can see, on my computer screen, my heart beat. [Want to test biofeedback / controlling of heart rate.]

Now, I know that there are those runner's bands that people wear on their chest that provides an approximate heart rate every minute, and some of them even has a usb port to provide a time series after the fact.

However, I want real time data.

Question: Where can I get (what are these things even called?) a wireless device that can (1) measure my heart rate in real time and (2) broadcast it in wifi or bluetooth .. or anything I can pick up with a PC?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Any updated experiments around 2016/17?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want one of these things:  [TI EZ430-Chronos](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-chronos)

Basically it's a watch with an interface for those pulse-rate sensors, and some other type of wireless link to PC's.  Oh, and of course you can program the microcontroller in the watch to do whatever you want.

If that didn't get your pulse rate up, here's some more things:  3-axis accelerometer, pressure sensor, temp sensor, 96-segment LCD, and USB dongles for wirelessly connecting to a PC.

The best part, it's [available for US$50](https://estore.ti.com/Search.aspx?k=ez430-chronos)!

Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 0):

You can get an ANT+ heartrate strap from Garmin or similar and an ANT dongle to plug into your computer.

If your PC has Bluetooth Smart (previously known as Bluetooth 4.0) (previously known as Bluetooth Low Energy) (previously known as Wibree) (previously known as Bluetooth Low End Extension) then you should look at the Wahoo HR strap: http://www.dcrainmaker.com/2012/01/wahoo-fitness-blue-hr-bluetooth-low.html

You can also find HR straps with normal Bluetooth, but the power consumption will be high, necessitating a rechargeable battery instead of the coin cell in the ANT+ / BLE straps.